# simile exhibit ie7 bug

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, timeline, simile

'm using to Exhibit to, pretty simply, display some data on
historical events and book publication dates:
http://f1shw1ck.com/timeline3/exhibit.html

Everything works fine, and I have been able to get the timeline
running as wanted, until I try to take control of the timeline with a
timelineConfig script. After I add this, my timeline continues to work
as expected on all browsers, except for IE.  Curiously enough, band 0
initializes and is rendered correctly, but band 1 shows no events and
does not sync to the band above. But it is picking up the width: 10%",
intervalUnit: Timeline.DateTime.DECADE, intervalPixels: 60
specifications, as they are rendered correctly.

Since everything works until I call ex:configuration="timelineConfig",
since everything works in the other browsers, and since everything
almost works in IE, up to the event painting, I have to imagine this
is a javascript coding error on my part, but I just can't see it. All
I get in my console is  Failed to create view View As Timeline."

Incidentally, having or not having the gotoYear function seemingly
does nothing to change...

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply an IE bug. I don't think there are active maintainers on this project, so...